# Kotlin check if function requires instance parameter

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

If a `KCallable` is created using `Any()::toString` then when it's later referenced you don't need to pass that `Any` instance (when using `call`).

Though if it's created using `Any::toString` (not an instance of `Any`) it's required to pass an `Any` instance.

So my question is how can I easily find out whether I need to pass that instance parameter and is this parameter mandatory?

I found a way to do this:

`callable.parameters[0].kind == KParameter.Kind.INSTANCE`

but it isn't quite nice and I wonder if there's an easier or recommended way to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement of the method you suggested is to check the [`instanceParameter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/instance-parameter.html) property: if it is not null, then the callable expects an instance:

```
val isInstanceCallable = callable.instanceParameter != null
```

Also, extension functions like `fun Any.foo() = ...` will have null in the `instanceParameter`, and you likely want to check the [`extensionReceiverParameter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/extension-receiver-parameter.html) as well.

---

Also, if you only need to work with callable references, you can check whether they have a bound receiver (i.e. the instance that it is bound to). Use the [`boundReceiver`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/CallableReference.java#L72) property:

```
val instance = (callable as CallableReference).boundReceiver
```

When a callable reference is unbound, it will return a special value `CallableReference.NO_RECEIVER`, therefore you just need to compare the returned value with it:

```
val bound = (callable as CallableReference).boundReceiver != CallableReference.NO_RECEIVER
```

[<sup>(runnable example)</sup>](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/ej4v0lsv15ejct4d8akvpe5ubt/jnak5d672nk15ii8rldtdtt50t)

Comment: So when `instanceParameter` returns null it means that I don't need to pass the callable owner, right?

Comment: Almost. There are also extension functions: `fun Any.foo() = 1`: it will have `instanceParameter == null`, so you probably want to check `extensionReceiverParameter` as well.